# Share asp.net login credentials with WinRT app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-runtime

Is there a way to setup a WinRT app and an ASP.NET site so that they share the same login credentials? I would like to set them up so that the user will create an account on the website and then be able to use the same username and password to log in to the app. If possible, I would like to avoid using an authentication service (like Facebook or a Microsoft Account). I would also like to save the certificate in the Password Vault so that the user can log in if they don't have an internet connection.

I found a similar question asked here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8e56f0a3-11b8-4f05-812e-d2415f0cb44f/how-to-login-with-winrt-and-aspnet-web-api-or-mvc?forum=winappswithcsharp. The answer provided by Anne Jing appears to be the answer I'm looking for, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually get it to work.

Comment: What part has you tripped up?

Comment: I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, so I guess the first thing I need help with is how to create a webservice to get the user's certificate and send it back to the WinRT app.